# How can you take a horse home without a saddle?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I've got a small problem. I've found a horse, but I don't have a saddle. However, I would still like to take him home, because I haven't had a horse before, and they're really useful (running is really inconvenient for food).

Is there any way to do this, or do I have to leave the horse to live a lonely, despawn death?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can attach a rope leash to it and guide it home that way. A leash is made with string and slime, as follows:

[image: Recipe of Lead]

If you need to take a break, you can tether the horse to a fence. This allows you to wander off and do whatever you need to do. Provided you remember where he/she is, you can return and get the horse back later.

More information can be found [on the wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Lead).

Comment: Oh, my fault for not reading the Wiki. I thought it only held them on! I'll accept when I can.

Comment: Look out - currently the code for leash seem to be bugged, it vanishes if you travel too far away and the chunk with the horse unloads. It's better to fence the horse in - note it can't pass through 1-wide gaps so you can e.g. make an enclosure of 2-block tall posts of any blocks placed with 1-block gap.